# Can I use click event without clicking

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

When we click a link on a website, click event performed and browser redirect to link's target so that in target page referral address become previous site adress.

I want to open a link in a website without clicking.
For example, I want open a website (for example cnn.com or any) and with console of browser, simulate clicking event that «browser» opens one of links.
I don't need the code opens that link directly, But also I need a code or extension that force browser to open one of link referral.

Please notice that, We can't access the host, for example suppose that we had to open a link of stackoverflow.com without clicking.

Thanks

Comment: There are special ways you can literally make it click from firefox addons, if you want to do that let us know. The methods vary as you may need the element to be visible on screen.

Comment: I'd like to you say @Noitidart

Comment: In Firefox we have some extra utilities which triggers an exact click, however the element and window must be visible on screen, here are the utilities: https://github.com/Noitidart/ChromeUtils we can also use js-ctypes to physicall move the mouse and click. If you want to trigger without focus, I think the only options are `.click()` or programatically using the firefox event inspector to figure out what triggers on click/mousedown/etc and then fire that function. The chrome utilities for firefox synth events like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simulate a click.

```
$("#yourLink").click();
```

or,

```
$("#yourLink").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Dear @Script47, Question Edited.

Comment: @Sheede I'm curious, why are you restricted to the console.

Comment: We can't access the host, for example suppose that we had to open a link of stackoverflow.com without clicking.

Comment: Can I simulate all links, and can I schedule this actions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
var element = document.getElementById('link');

// Trigger click event on Safari using createEvent
if(document.createEvent) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else {
    element.click();
}
```

Note : For Safari you will have to create an event and dispatch it.

Comment: This code where be written? We can't access the host! @Sanjeev

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery click or trigger click here is the document   https://api.jquery.com/click/
https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Dear @juan, We can't access the codes of site, for example suppose that we had to open a link of stackoverflow.com without clicking.

Comment: If you can get the href value you can make a window relocation to the link address you have do you have it?

Comment: That would be window.location.href=your location

Comment: No @juan, Because if I open this link, it is directive opening and new page referral is empty! I need to after triggering or redirecting, referral of new page will be "stackoverflow.com"